# How to make color in agendaWeek change if the time less than time chosen

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I want to ask, in `FullCalendar` in `agendaWeek` and `agendaDay`, can I make the time disable ? The problem is like in `agendaDay`, we can make agenda at anytime of the day. I want,if time now is afternoon like 1pm, the time in morning (like 5 am) is disabled and the color is changed. So the user can't choose the time before real time to make an agenda.

I have tried using `element.find('.fc-widget-content').append("<div style='color:#000'>");`  in `select:function(start, end, allDay, jsEvent, view)` but it the color isn't change.

Here's the code

```
 select:function(start, end, allDay, jsEvent, view)
 {
        var enddate2 = moment(end).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
                // console.log(end)

        var startdate = moment(start).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
        var starttime = moment(start).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm');
        var timenow = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm');
        var endtime = moment(end).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm');
        var enddate = moment(end).subtract(1, 'days').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
        var starts = moment(start).format('HH:mm');
        var ends = moment(end).format('HH:mm');

        if (view.name === "agendaDay")
        {
              if(starttime < timenow)          
              {
                 element.find('.fc-widget-content').append("<div style='color:#000'>"); 
              }
         }
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `append` function just appends the given string to the element. If you are using `jQuery` you can use `element.find('.fc-widget-content').css('color', '#000');`

Comment: it still doesn't work

Comment: `color` changes the text color. Make sure you don't already have black colored texts and `element.find('.fc-widget-content')` function returns the elements